# DataStructure to cache a large set of Chart DataPoints

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, charts

I have a scenario like I am plotting a Chart using API like JFreeChart or SWT Chart or BIRT anything is fine.
 The data for plotting the chart is bit high like 10GB. So how chart works is it just keep the latest data points like X,Y and discard other data for efficient memory utilization.

> Like I got a scenario that once that is done a user comes and try to
>   zoom the chart or wanna see the certain specific DataPoints , so solve
>   this scenario I need to cache all the data points in the chart that
>   will again take the memory on toss as if I need to save entire data
>   points it may lead to huge memory.

So what is the most efficient algorithm or precisely any DataStructure to sort this problem.
It is nothing to do with java but I am programming in Java , so I mentioned Java here.

Comment: What's your data look like?

Comment: X and Y values , Int values  as of now. But its not limited. It can be any object or anything.